# Using Arrays in Visual C#?

Tags: c#, arrays, function

I have a function that takes an array as a parameter. The function then fills the array up with information of unknown length. So how would I create an array to store a message of unknown length? Because I can't specify the size of the array since I don't know the size of the message it is going to store.

Would this be valid?

```
byte [] array;
function (array);
```

And then the size of the array will be determined by the size of the message it is filled in? 
If this isn't possible how would I do this?

I need the array to be the exact size of the message it is filled up with, so I can't just specify the array to be some random size big enough to fit the message.

---

Additional, from a comment:

```
public int ReceiveFrom( byte[] buffer, int offset, int size, 
       SocketFlags socketFlags, ref EndPoint remoteEP )
```

Comment: You can't. And that's why such interfaces don't exist in the library.

Comment: @DarrenYoung: one valid reason for downvoting is that the relevant info (again) has to be extracted form comments. The misunderstanding that caused the question is excusable, the (far) too short question itself is not. Also look at Fahrad's previosu question.

Comment: @HenkHolterman
I specifically didn't specify the function prototype for a reason:
The function that I mentioned is not the only function which is giving me a problem. In addition I have several other functions which is giving me the same problem. I cannot and will not waste time posting a variety of prototypes when the question is so generalized.

Comment: @Fahrad - one example would have cleared up a lot. As it finally did.

Comment: @HenkHolterman Your right, that was a fault on my part. I will be more specific next time.

Comment: @Farhad why not change your functions to accept List><T> ? you can always later convert to array. The whole purpose of list is to work with arrays of unknown sizes

Comment: Thanks, but I do not have control over the function prototype. The problem has been resolved anyway.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

About using

```
public int ReceiveFrom( byte[] buffer, int offset, int size, 
   SocketFlags socketFlags, ref EndPoint remoteEP )
```

You are supposed to use this in a loop. You are receiving parts of the total message (stream) at a time. Up to you to decide which part you need. Optionally shift the rest down and specify an `offset` in the next call.

```
byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
ínt n;
do 
{
    n = ReceiveFrom(buffer, 0, buffer.Lenght, ...);

    if (n > 0)
        // process n bytes in buffer

} while (n > 0);
```

Comment: Thanks. The looping would only be required for TCP sockets though right? Or would this be for UDP sockets too?

Comment: I don't know UDP sockets but I'm quite certain it works the same way.

Comment: UDP is datagram-oriented, not stream-oriented. The buffer needs to be large enough to hold the entire datagram (up to 64 KiB). Otherwise the data gets truncated and the method throws a SocketException.

Comment: Thank You- I guess I won't need to loop then.

Answer (score 3):

You can use a List and then once your message is filled call [ToArray](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x303t819.aspx)

Edit

Example:

```
List<byte> message = new List<byte>();
message.Add(/*your byte*/);
//More Adds
function(message.ToArray());
```

Comment: Not going to help. OP has no control over the method implementation or its signature, so passing anything other than an array is not possible.

Comment: I see that now. That wasn't obvious before he commented on your answer.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a [List](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6sh2ey19.aspx) instead. Although possible, you don't need to set a predetermined length and the List will expand as more objects are added.

Comment: It specifically has to be an array.

Comment: Why does it have to be an array?  You can't have a dynamic array.

Comment: Because the function only accepts an array as a parameter. Also the array doesn't have to be dynamic - as in it doesn't have to keep changing sizes. I just need its initial size to be determined by the function.

Comment: Does that mean you have no control over the function? (i.e. change it?)

Comment: @Farhad: And why again must it be an array? You need a data structure to put the message in. Why don't you just use a string? Or a specific object?

Comment: Unfortunately no I don't. If this is not possible, I could give the array an extremely large size guaranteed to fit the message. However then I would need to be able to check upto what index the array is full. i.e I give the array a size of 1000. When the function returns, I need to check how much of the array is filled.Any idea how I could check how many indexes of the array is filled?

Comment: @JohnnyGraber Because the function only accepts an array of bytes.

Comment: I don't have control over what the function returns and its parameters.

Comment: @Farhad - Can you post the function's signature?

Comment: @Farhad - With such limits, it seems the only solution is to create an array that's guaranteed to be large enough. Then, once the array is filled, you can 'compress' the array by resizing it to match the exact number of elements within it.

Comment: @Farhad: Such functions do not exist because you could not use them. Look again.

Comment: public int ReceiveFrom(
 byte[] buffer,
 int offset,
 int size,
 SocketFlags socketFlags,
 ref EndPoint remoteEP
)

Comment: @HenkHolterman The function can be used normally with a fixed size array. However I need to compare the size's of the message received and I can't do this if my array isn't the exact size of the message.

Comment: @Fahrad: I thought so. You are just misunderstanding how socket I/O works.

Comment: Please see the MSDN documentation regarding use of Socket.ReceiveFrom. It describes fairly well how it is intended to be called. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kbfwcz73.aspx

Comment: @HenkHolterman Your right. I'm sorry I didn't read the complete documentation and didn't realize the function returns the number of bytes stored. I thought it just returned true upon a successful read. Thank You and Sorry for the waste of time.

Answer (score 0):

Do you need to do something with the array before passing it to the function that fills it up? If you don't, why don't you just return the array from the function instead of passing it one:

```
byte[] retArray = function();
```

where function is:

```
byte[] function()
{
}
```

You can then find out the length of the array by checking:

```
if( retArray != null )
{
  Console.WriteLine( retArray.Count );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to tell without knowing the exact details, but you could let the function create the array after it knows the length of the information.

Additionally, with Linq (using [ToArray](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x303t819.aspx) and [ToList](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb342261.aspx)) you can cast from and to arrays and lists, but again, it's hard to tell without knowing the intentions.